# jQuery add 1 up with a php foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, foreach, count

So I have this php `foreach`-loop that gets data from my database.
I use a `$i++` to number up the same div.

```
$i=0;
foreach ($pages as $page){
    echo '<div class="class_'.$i++.'">
    echo '</div>';          
}
```

Now I have a piece of jQuery in my footer that does something to the `<div>`

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.class_1');
    $('.class_2');
    $('.class_3');
});
</script>
```

Because I will never know how many instances there are I want the jQuery to add up with the `foreach`-loop but the script is outside the loop so it won't add up.

I don't really know my jQuery that much so any help would be appreciated.

M.

Comment: Why do you need this? The whole point of classes is to group elements together. Depending on your need, it would be better to put a single class on all the elements and then use the `this` reference within the event handler to reference the one which raised the event.

Comment: `class` is used for a group of elements. You could instead give them a single class with different id numbers

Comment: I see what you mean but every class has it's own function and own css. So it's not really combined. It could have been id's as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i=0;
foreach ($pages as $page){
    echo '<div class="class_'.$i++.'">';
    echo '</div>';          
}
echo '<div number-of-divs=' . $i . ' style="display:none;"/>';
```

Your js code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var number = $('div[number-of-divs]').attr('number-of-divs');
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) { 
        $('.class_' + i);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get every element with that class and then use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for it.

```
$('[class^="class_"]').each(function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach for this is you should pass another class in your code or pass this only if above is the only case.  `$('[class^="class_"]').each(function() {});` This will not work in  some cases so use below code

```
$i=0;
foreach ($pages as $page){
    echo '<div class="catch_me  class_'.$i++.'">
    echo '</div>';          
}
```

and get it from this script

```
$('.catch_me').each(function(){
//You code here
});
```